# getting correct names for Dbpedia sparqlwrapper queries

Tags: python-3.x, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I am querying DBpedia for information about organizations and I am using "dbpedia.org/page/[organization]" to find what name is used for those organizations. It will usually fix the inputted name to the name it uses. eg dbpedia.org/page/Tmobile will be redirected to T-Mobile.

When making a query using SPARQLwrapper to 'http://dbpedia.org/sparql' these names usually work but not always (such as the previous T-Mobile example. How can I find the specific name to use when querying DBpedia using SPARQLwrapper?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you're using the wrong URIs for your SPARQL queries -- `.../page/...` are HTML representations of the descriptions of the entities. `.../resource/...` are the identifiers of the entities (which get redirected to the `.../page/...` when you use a web browser, which requests HTML, to dereference the `.../resource/...` URIs).

In other words, instead of, for instance (results [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fpage%2FTmobile%3E&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)) --

```
DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/page/Tmobile>
```

-- try (results [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FTmobile%3E&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)) --

```
DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tmobile>
```